# Sort Nested Hash Inside Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I have sample data like this:

```
[
  [{"calendar"=>{:start_date=>Thu, 07 Aug 2014, :title=>"Recurring Event Test", :has_downloads=>false, :description=>"<p>Recurring content</p>\r\n", :location=>"Lunch hall", :id=>243, :end_date=>Thu, 07 Aug 2014}}],
  [{"calendar"=>{:start_date=>Wed, 06 Aug 2014, :title=>"Single event", :has_downloads=>false, :description=>"<p>for date 6th</p>\r\n", :location=>"chennai", :id=>253, :end_date=>Wed, 06 Aug 2014}}] 
]
```

Need to **sort** this values by `start_date` field.

I tried like this

```
sort_by {|vn| vn[:start_date]}
```

its showing error nil class

Comment: What have you tried already, possibly after having a look at the various [sort methods of arrays](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sort)? Please show us the code. What were the issues with your approach?

Comment: why are you calling `:datetime`

Comment: You have an array of arrays, so do something like `sort_by {|x| x.first[:start_date]}`

Comment: @Grych am getting this error Symbol as array index - (TypeError)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vn` is an Array and `start_date` is nested inside `calendar`. You should do

```
arr.sort_by {|vn| vn[0]["calendar"][:start_date]}
```

Comment: Your old answer only working... arr.sort_by {|vn| vn["calendar"][:start_date]}

Comment: In your question, you have an array of arrays. If my previous answer works, then you probably have an array of hashes.